# AJAX GET Request Being Ignored

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views

I am brand new to AJAX requests and I am still learning Django, but I have a project where the user enters an Elasticsearch query and then we generate a downloadable document (report) for the user.

I have an AJAX request to continuously check on the existence of a file in my `form.html` file and it doesn't seem to be getting picked up at all. I can tell this because it isn't giving me any alerts and it's just automatically timing out on big requests after ~30 seconds.

I tried to write a temporary fix in my `views.py` that is basically attempting to do what the javascript in `form.html` is doing, but A) I feel like this isn't the best method to use in production, B) it doesn't feel like a good use of time to essentially re-invent the wheel, and C) I want the user to get some sort of alert or indication on their end that the report is in progress, and then when it's ready to download.

How can I modify my code to actually perform the AJAX request? Or why does it appear that the AJAX request isn't working?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('form/', include('audit_tool.urls')),
    path('report/', include('audit_tool.urls')),
    path('check_progress/', views.check_progress, name='check_progress'),
    # path('return_doc/', views.return_doc, name='return_doc'),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STAT)
```

**audit_tool/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_query, name='form'),
]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STAT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from docx import Document
import os
import threading
from .forms import QueryForm
from .models import *


@login_required
def get_query(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data["query"]
            fn = str(time.time()).replace(".", "_") + ".docx"
            t = threading.Thread(target=generate_doc, args=(query, fn))
            t.start()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/check_progress/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your query does not appear to be valid. Please enter a valid query and try again.")
    else:
        form = QueryForm()
        return render(request, 'icm_audit_tool/form_template.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def check_progress(request):
    """
    Returns whether document generation is complete or in progress
    """
    fn = request["filename"]
    file = "/app/created_files/" + fn
    while not os.path.exists(file):
        time.sleep(10)
        if os.path.exists(file):
            doc = Document(file)
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(fn)
            doc.save(response)
            return response
```

**form.html**

```
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
    var checkInterval = setInterval(isFileComplete, 10000); //10000 is 10 seconds

    function isFileComplete() {

        $.ajax({
        url: '/check_progress/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.file_created) {
                alert("Your file is ready to download!");
                clearInterval(checkInterval);
            } else {
                alert("Your report is still being created, please hold.");
                checkInterval;
            }
        }
    });
   }
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**base_login.html**

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="link/to/company/iconicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
    <title>Audit Report Tool</title>
  </head>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dept</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="../">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="../admin">Admin</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">
        <img src="{% static "logo.png" %}" alt="Company Logo" align="left"></img>
        <img src="{% static "logo.png" %}" alt="Dept Logo" align="right" width="140" height="140"></img>
        <h1 align="center"><font size="6"> Audit Report Tool</font></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
  <main>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </main>
{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But your `check_progress`  view blocks until the file is present. Why are you doing that? That's not what anytime said to do in your previous question. It means the Ajax response will never return until then, defeating the whole purpose.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you explain exactly which part of the code it blocks? I wrote it the way I wrote it just to have it do what it should be doing in form.html so I have something working but it's clearly not doing what I want and I'm looking for advice on what I should be doing instead. How can I change it to stop it blocking the Ajax response?

Comment: In the while loop. Why do you have that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have the while loop so that it will continuously check if the file exists on an interval. I did this because my Ajax request wasn't happening, so I added the while loop so I could have something working to check if the file exists but it clearly isn't adding any value. This question contains what my view looked like before I added the for loop. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798192/django-app-not-communicating-with-javascript-code-block/56798468)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on that question, you need to put `block javascript` in the base template so that the block contents have somewhere to go.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I do have that in my base template, which I added to the original question. I reverted to my old code just to test it out again, and it's still not working.

Comment: No you don't. base_login.html in that question does not contain `{% block javascript %}`

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes but I added `{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}` to base_login.html in this question. Or, did I misunderstand and I should move my javascript block from form.html to base_login.html?